# create a file and insert a line

Tags: javascript, html

I want that when the user presses the div, a new file will be created and the line: `Testing 1, 2, 3.` will be inserted.

I tried the next thing:

```
<div  id="rect0" onclick="CreateFile();" style="height: 85px; width: 85px; background-color:#ff0000; ">Hello</div>

<script>
    function CreateFile()
    {
       var fso, tf;
       fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
       tf = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\Log\\logJscript2.txt", true);

       tf.WriteLine("Testing 1, 2, 3.") ;

       tf.Close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ActiveXObject just works on IE

Comment: Which browser and version are you targeting?

Comment: So, you've done this, what's the problem? The snippet is correct (though for IE only). What you want to ask?

Comment: I want it to work on Chrome.

Comment: I found this link: http://svn.tiddlywiki.org/Trunk/core/jquery/plugins/jQuery.twFile.js

what should I write in my javascript file? $.twFile.save("c:\\Log\\logJscript2.txt", "my line");

Comment: No, you can't get your code to work in Chrome, or any other browser but IE. You'll need something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage) in Chrome and other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, JavaScript cannot do this. It's a huge security issue if it could. Imagine a browser downloading any file it likes without the user knowing about it like you propose here.